# Convert void into async return in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I read that returning `void` from a C# `async` call is not good. But I have the following scenario:

```
public async void MainFunction()
{
    await DoSomething()
    await DoSomethingMore()
}

public void DoSomething() 
{
    //some code that I want to execute (fire and forget)
}

public void DoSomethingMore()
{
    //some code that I want to execute (fire and forget)
}
```

Since I just want that function be executed with no return at all. Should i keep it like this, or should I return `Task` from DoSomething()? If I change it to return Task, since my code doesn't need to return anything at all, what should I return?

Comment: You cannot `await` these methods - they are not marked as async.

Comment: well the `Main` cannot be `async`.

Comment: @shay__ Aaaah, no - you can't `await` these methods because they don't return a task (or more exactly, an awaitable) - `async` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You probably think that await starts something. No, it waits for something that is already running.

Comment: @Luaan You **can** await `public async void DoSomenting()`, that's what I meant.

Comment: @shay__ Not in my compiler. It just means that you don't have to return a task explicitly, but the method signature still must have `Task` (or another awaitable) as the return type.

Comment: @shay__ you can never await a method, you await an awaitable value. Most often a Task. `void` is not a value and is not awaitable. `async` has zero impact on callers.

Comment: Yes you are both right, I was commenting too fast without even thinking =\  thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If i change it to return Task, since my code need return nothing at
>   all, what should i return?

Your current code wouldn't compile, as you can't `await` on a `void` returning method (because it doesn't return an awaitable, which is a type which exposes a `GetAwaiter` method).

Any `void` method in the synchronous world should return a `Task` in the asynchronous world. This allows for anyone who wishes to asynchronously wait on the async operation, and also gets a chance to handle exceptions properly. using `async void` means that the exception will either be swallowed, or if set to in the configuration, will be rethrown on an arbitrary threadpool thread. Async should be propagated properly all the way.

Note that when you await both operations in `MainFunctionAsync`, you're not firing and forgetting, you're asynchronously waiting for each of them to complete, sequentially.

```
public async Task MainFunctionAsync()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
    await DoSomethingMoreAsync();
}

public Task DoSomethingAsync() 
{
    // Do meaningful async stuff
}

public Task DoSomethingMoreAsync()
{
    // Do more meaningful async stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can return either of these

```
Task.FromCompleted;
Task.FromException(ex);
```

so your method would be like this:

```
public void MainFunction()
{
    await DoSomething()
    await DoSomethingMore()
}

public Task DoSomething() 
{
    try{

     //some code that I want to execute (fire and forget)

     return Task.FromCompleted;
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
     return Task.FromException(ex);
   }

}


    //some code that I want to execute (fire and forget)
}

public Task DoSomethingMore()
{
       try{

     //some code that I want to execute (fire and forget)

     return Task.FromCompleted;
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
     return Task.FromException(ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice inclusion of Task.FromException
Just as a note it seems like from .Net 4.8 you should use Task.CompletedTask https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.8